# Accessing elements in two dimensional BYTE array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to use a function provided in 3rd party documentation and am having trouble getting my head around it. I recently figured out the meaning of IN/OUT variables and how to work with them. The problem with this function is it has several different types all combined. I am really confused how to access these array elements. Provided below is a screenshot of the function information.

[image]

This is the code I am working with:

```
BYTE numDevices = 10;
    BYTE devices;
    ULONG devicesArray = QCWWAN2kEnumerateDevices(&numDevices,&devices);

    //How do I access the elements in the returned array?
```

**ULONG IS THE RETURN CODE TO SEE IF IT FAILED/WHY**

Comment: What is the library you are using ? What does the documentation of the library says about QCWWAN2kEnumerateDevices ? In particular what is its signature.

Comment: The image above is all the information on the function sadly.

Comment: So, do we assume the devices array is going to be a two-dimensional array (array of pointers to structs) or a one-dimensional array (an array of structs).  I persnally think it is the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a debugger on it. It is unclear whether the QCWWAN2kEnumerateDevices allocates memory for your devices. If it doesn't (I doubt it does, knowing Win32API) your

> BYTE devices;

should instead be

```
struct DEVICE_ARRAY_ELEM {
char devID[256];
char devKey[16];
};
DEVICE_ARRAY_ELEM *pDevices = malloc(sizeof(DEVICE_ARRAY_ELEM) * 10);
ULONG devicesArray = QCWWAN2kEnumerateDevices(&numDevices, (pDevices);
//Do stuff
free((void *)pDevices);
```

EDIT___ sorry that was C, here it is in C++

```
struct DEVICE_ARRAY_ELEM {
char devID[256];
char devKey[16];
};
DEVICE_ARRAY_ELEM *pDevices = new DEVICE_ARRAY_ELEM[10];
ULONG devicesArray = QCWWAN2kEnumerateDevices(&numDevices, pDevices);
//do stuff
delete [] pDevices;
```

To access use:

```
pDevices[devnum].devID[IDIndex];
```

Comment: where's the free (delete) man! lol.  a cast to `BYTE*` is also needed when passing in `pDevices`.  And when defining a struct, you need to use it as `struct DEVICE_ARRAY_ELEM` or `typedef` it to `DEVICE_ARRAY_ELEM`

Comment: And to access a 2d array use pDevices[devnum]->devID[IDIndex];

Comment: Yep, need your type safety too, but any compiler will flag that. Back I go to being managed.

Comment: are you sure `pDevices[devnum]->devID` shouldn't be `pDevices[devnum].devID` since you allocated an array of structs and not an array of pointers?

Comment: It's hard with 600 res netbook!

Comment: @0A0D what pointer?, the array is of structs, not pointers to a struct

Comment: There is no explanation in that image that devicesArray is a ULONG or what the ULONG is, so it is confusing to say ULONG devicesArray.

Comment: @Bob: Go here : http://www.idleloop.com/tutorials/introC/MemoryAndPointers.pdf you don't need a pointer, but this method requires.

Comment: @0A0D that is why I say in my answer it is the number of devices put into the array

Comment: ulong is the returning code. It allows me to see if it failed/why

Comment: @Bob: No you didn't say that.

Comment: I get an error with pDevices saying : ERROR argument of type BYTE is incompatible with type BYTE*

Answer (score 0):

Improving upon John Silver's answer

```
// IN A HEADER:
typedef struct DEVICE_ARRAY_ELEM {
    char devID[256];
    char devKey[16];
} DEVICE_ARRAY_ELEM; //  This defines a struct to hold the data brought back
// it also type defs 'struct DEVICE_ARRAY_ELEM' to 'DEVICE_ARRAY_ELEM' for convienence

// IN YOUR CODE:
// This pointer should be wrapped in a auto_ptr to help with RAII
DEVICE_ARRAY_ELEM *pDevices = new DEVICE_ARRAY_ELEM[10]; // allocate 10 elements in-line
ULONG errorCode = QCWWAN2kEnumerateDevices(&numDevices, (BYTE*)pDevices); // get them

// Here is the hard part: iterating over the array of devices returned
// as per the spec numDevices is now the number of devices parsed
for(int i = 0; i < numDevices; i++) {
   printf("%s\n", pDevices[i].devID); // is the name of the device (a character array)
}

delete [] pDevices;
```

### EDIT

I now use `numDevices` do iterate over the array since the spec says that is the number of devices enumerated after the function call

### EDIT AGAIN

Here is the code working based on my assumptions: [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/0rfEo)

The code has some `typedef`s and a definition of what I think the `QCWWAN2kEnumerateDevices` operates.  So those should be ignored, but the code is compiles and performs as expected

Comment: When I put your code into VS it underlines **printf("%s\n", pDevices[i].devID)** and says Error: Expression must have class type.

Comment: maybe the semicolon needed at the end of that line (my bad)

Comment: the ULONG return is for returning error codes. Also, the semicolon did not fix the error message.

Comment: You are not dereferencing. Do you know C++?

Comment: @danes look at the IDEONE code (minus my typedefs and library function definition at the top), tell me if that is what you have, because that seems to be working, or at least it works in the way I think the internals of the library function work.

Comment: @0A0D, if i make that `.` a `->` it blows up...I can't dereference a struct: `prog.cpp:31: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘DEVICE_ARRAY_ELEM’`

Comment: @DeadMG I know, I should wrap the pointer in an auto_ptr, but I don't know if he has access to STL and wants to deal with that quite yet.